# SelectAll method in custom TextBox (Winforms .NET 7)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have made a Custom TextBox that is a panel with a TextBox inside.

What i'm trying to do is `[CustomTextBox name].SelectAll();` where it
returns `[TextBox nameInsideCustomControl].SelectAll();`

`[...]` is just a name.

How can i implement it?

I have tried:

```
[Category("Custom")]
public void SelectAll
{
    get { textBox1.SelectAll(); }
}
```

But i don't think it's right.

Answer:
`public void SelectAll() => textBox1.SelectAll();`. It's a method, not a property. –
dr.null

Comment: `public void SelectAll() => textBox1.SelectAll();`. It's a method, not a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `CustomTextBox` that inherits from `Panel` and you want to be able to select all text in the `TextBox` that it contains.

[image: screenshot]

To achieve this objective, first make sure that your `CustomTextBox` exposes a pubic method named `SelectAll` that forwards the command to the private `TextBox` it contains. But *in addition to that* you will either need to make sure that the internal `TextBox` receives focus *or* set the `HideSelection` property of the internal `TextBox` to `false`. Otherwise you may still not see the selection highlighted.

---

**Custom Text Box example**

```
public partial class CustomTextBox : Panel
{
    public void SelectAll()
    {
        textBox1.SelectAll();
        // Ensure text box gets the focus.
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
    public void LoadTestData() => 
        textBox1.Text = "Don't forget to give Focus to the TextBox!";
    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        BackColor= Color.Azure;
        label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();

        #region I N I T I A L I Z E
        SuspendLayout();

        label1.AutoSize = true;
        label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 17);
        label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(143, 25);
        label1.TabIndex = 0;
        label1.Text = "Custom Text Box";

        textBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190, 17);
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
        textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(206, 126);
        textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        textBox1.HideSelection = false;

        Controls.Add(textBox1);
        Controls.Add(label1);
        Name = "CustomTextBox";
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(424, 157);
        ResumeLayout(false);
        PerformLayout();
        #endregion I N I T I A L I Z E
    }
    private Label label1;
    private TextBox textBox1;
}
```

---

**Minimal Test Code**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        customTextBoxPanel.LoadTestData();
        buttonSelectAllTest.Click += onClickSelectAllTest;
    }

    private void onClickSelectAllTest(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customTextBoxPanel.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```
[custom textbox name].SelectAll();
```

I don't know why you were confused .. it works all right for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).